# "Pin to Start Menu" option is unavailable to one program, but is available to others, in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, start-menu

I want to pin a program to the start menu, but the option "Pin to Start Menu" is not available when right clicking the link to the program. The option is available when right-clicking other programs.

Here is a screen shot of the program without the option, and IE with the option (the option is available to any other program I tested, not only MS programs, except for the one wanted).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft has decided to create a list of reserved file name words that cannot be pinned to start menu.
Some of which include:

Documentation, Help, Install, More Info, Readme, Read me, Read First, Setup, Support, What's New, Remove.

Remove "Setup" from the file name and you should be able to pin it.